# Open new Activity inside Activity

Tags: android

I would like to know if it is possible to open a new Activity(at least, the view of the activity) in small inside another Activity as whatsApp does when it sends the position.

When you click on "send position", the current activity opens a new one where a map appears in small.

Thanks.

Comment: you mean like a dialog box that doesn't take up the full screen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure, yes.  For example, that's what happens when one of your activities takes a camera picture, or uses a map.  It can just as easily be one of your own, custom activities that you invoke.  You can, of course, set the size to be whatever you'd like.

Here's a good example, illustrating what the author calls "sub-Activities":

http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=302

Comment: This is not "a new Activity... in small **inside another Activity**" (emphasis mine).

Comment: I don´t understand why, but the Eclipse doesn´t recognize the method startSubActivity(i, Global.WIDGET_REQ_CODE);

Comment: server is unavailable, could you post solution here in short?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html)

Comment: I can´t use fragments.....Fragments are available from Android 3.0 and I am using Android 2.2 for my project. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @jorgeAndroid use Android Compatability Library v4

Answer (score 1):

Embedded Activities via ActivityGroup were a nice idea, but have always been difficult to deal with since Activity is designed to be an independent self-contained component instead of closely interacting with other activities. The Fragment API is a much better solution for this, and should be considered as a replacement for embedded activities.

You can use Fragments since Android 1.6 Donut through the [**Support Library**](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/extras/support-library.html)